# Writing a REST API for an entity with 18 dependencies

Tags: php, json, rest, angular

I'm writing a REST API to expose a table to an Angular frontend, and I've run across this situation:
The data I need to display is located, aside from the class corresponding to the main entity (we'll call it "Ticket"), in about 10 other tables. The data in some of these must be accessed by examining the relationships established between those rows by rows in a number of associative entities. In total, I need to query 19 tables in order to display the complete dataset pertaining to one Ticket row.

The difficulty is this: I can write code in this API to retrieve the data from all these other tables -- sure, no problem, just something like 25 method calls, which, while probably a little slow, is tolerable. But in order to return the data to the frontend, the GET response will wind up consisting of a contorted chunk of JSON containing varying numbers of members at the different levels. This will make utilizing the data with Angular difficult due to the complexity and therefore fragility of the JSON. 
The other end of this problem is POSTing and PUTing data with regards to Angular. The form/s to modify a Ticket can either hook up to the same structure to minimize HTTP requests (constructing some disgusting JSON, modifying little bits of it and sending the rest back untouched, etc) or can be wired up to individual REST endpoints to interface with the tables individually, sacrificing a great deal of speed in order to gain simplicity as far as payload is concerned.

This particular app (an internal corporate tool) will likely never have more than five or ten users logged in at any given moment, and so large amounts of traffic aren't a huge concern from the server standpoint, but making something like a dozen chained HTTP requests is obviously a horrendous design decision, while on the other hand, using an ad-hoc, largely conditionally structured JSON response to interface with Angular seems like an equally abhorrent design decision.

Any suggestions as to how this issue could be remedied? Am I stuck with one of these choices? Thanks.

Edit:
The database looks more or less like this (a simplified version).
Ticket has 6 FKs; relationships exist to every one of these tables through those 6 and the multiple associative tables.

```
CREATE TABLE profileType (
  profileTypeId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  profileTypeName VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (profileTypeName),
  PRIMARY KEY (profileTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE profile (
  profileId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  profileType INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  profileEmail VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  profileUserName VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  profileFirstName VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  profileLastName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  profileSalt CHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  profileHash CHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  profileActivationToken VARCHAR (32),

  INDEX (profileFirstName),
  INDEX (profileLastName),
  UNIQUE (profileEmail),
  UNIQUE (profileUserName),
  FOREIGN KEY (profileType) REFERENCES profileType (profileTypeId),
  PRIMARY KEY (profileId)
);

CREATE TABLE site (
  siteId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  siteName VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  siteLab VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  siteG2Id VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
  siteIsOsm TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  siteAsBuilt VARCHAR (128),

  INDEX (siteG2Id),
  INDEX (siteLab),
  INDEX (siteIsOsm),
  UNIQUE (siteName),
  PRIMARY KEY (siteId)
);

CREATE TABLE contact (
  contactId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  contactLandPhone CHAR (10),
  contactCellPhone CHAR (10),
  contactEmail VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  contactFirstName VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  contactLastName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,

  INDEX (contactLandPhone),
  INDEX (contactCellPhone),
  INDEX (contactFirstName),
  INDEX (contactLastName),
  UNIQUE (contactEmail),
  PRIMARY KEY (contactId)
);

CREATE TABLE contactType (
  contactTypeId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  contactTypeName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (contactTypeName),
  PRIMARY KEY (contactTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE contactContactType (
  contactContactTypeContactId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  contactContactTypeContactTypeId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (contactContactTypeContactId) REFERENCES contact (contactId),
  FOREIGN KEY (contactContactTypeContactTypeId) REFERENCES contactType (contactTypeId),
  PRIMARY KEY (contactContactTypeContactId, contactContactTypeContactTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE ticketCategory (
  ticketCategoryId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  ticketCategoryName VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (ticketCategoryName),
  PRIMARY KEY (ticketCategoryId)
);

CREATE TABLE ticketSubCategory (
  ticketSubCategoryId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  ticketSubCategoryCategoryId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketSubCategoryName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (ticketSubCategoryName),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketSubCategoryCategoryId) REFERENCES ticketCategory (ticketCategoryId),
  PRIMARY KEY (ticketSubCategoryId)
);

CREATE TABLE ticket (
  ticketId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  ticketSiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketCategory INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketSubCategory INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketCaller INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketCreatedBy INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketDateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ticketReason VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
  ticketSymptom VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
  ticketSummary VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  ticketLastEdited TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ticketLastEditedBy INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketIsStageTwo TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketIsResolved TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ticketResolvedDateTime TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  INDEX (ticketDateTime),
  INDEX (ticketIsStageTwo),
  INDEX (ticketIsResolved),
  INDEX (ticketResolvedDateTime),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketSiteId) REFERENCES site (siteId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketCategory) REFERENCES ticketCategory (ticketCategoryId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketSubCategory) REFERENCES ticketSubCategory (ticketSubCategoryId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketCaller) REFERENCES contact (contactId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketCreatedBy) REFERENCES profile (profileId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticketLastEditedBy) REFERENCES profile (profileId),
  PRIMARY KEY (ticketId)
);

CREATE TABLE message (
  messageId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  messageTicketId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  messageProfileId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  messageContent VARCHAR (2048),
  messageDateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  messageIsStageTwo TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  INDEX (messageDateTime),
  INDEX (messageIsStageTwo),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageTicketId) REFERENCES ticket (ticketId),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageProfileId) REFERENCES profile (profileId),
  PRIMARY KEY (messageId)
);

CREATE TABLE address (
  addressId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  addressSiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  addressStreetOne VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  addressStreetTwo VARCHAR (64),
  addressCity VARCHAR (64),
  addressState CHAR (2),
  addressZip CHAR (5),

  INDEX (addressCity),
  INDEX (addressState),
  INDEX (addressZip),
  FOREIGN KEY (addressSiteId) REFERENCES site(siteId),
  PRIMARY KEY (addressId)
);

CREATE TABLE sentry (
  sentryId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  sentrySiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sentrySn VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  sentryLocation VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  sentryName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  sentryEmail VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  sentryEmailUserName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  sentryIp VARBINARY (16) NOT NULL,
  sentryPort VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
  sentryMac CHAR (12) NOT NULL,
  sentryGateway VARBINARY (16) NOT NULL,
  sentryMask VARBINARY (16) NOT NULL,
  sentryFirmwareVersion VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
  sentryInstallDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

  INDEX (sentrySn),
  INDEX (sentryName),
  UNIQUE (sentryEmail),
  FOREIGN KEY (sentrySiteId) REFERENCES site(siteId),
  PRIMARY KEY (sentryId)
);

CREATE TABLE monitoring (
  monitoringId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  monitoringName VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  monitoringSecurity VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  monitoringObservation VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  monitoringSiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  monitoringSn VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  monitoringLocation VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  monitoringOs VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  monitoringSwVersion VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
  monitoringIp VARBINARY (16) NOT NULL,
  monitoringIsDhcp TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  monitoringOwnerIsYfh TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  monitoringInstallDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

  INDEX (monitoringSn),
  FOREIGN KEY (monitoringSiteId) REFERENCES site(siteId),
  PRIMARY KEY (monitoringId)
);

CREATE TABLE seal (
  sealId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  sealSiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sealSentryId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sealSn VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
  sealIsWireless TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  INDEX (sealSn),
  FOREIGN KEY (sealSiteId) REFERENCES site (siteId),
  FOREIGN KEY (sealSentryId) REFERENCES sentry (sentryId),
  PRIMARY KEY (sealId)
);

CREATE TABLE sealSatellite (
  sealSatelliteId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  sealSatelliteSealId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sealSatelliteSn VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (sealSatelliteSn),
  FOREIGN KEY (sealSatelliteSealId) REFERENCES seal (sealId),
  PRIMARY KEY (sealSatelliteId)
);

CREATE TABLE cap (
  capId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  capTicketId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  capProfileId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  capDateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  capIsStageTwo TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  capContent VARCHAR (2048) NOT NULL,

  INDEX (capIsStageTwo),
  FOREIGN KEY (capProfileId) REFERENCES profile (profileId),
  FOREIGN KEY (capTicketId) REFERENCES ticket (ticketId),
  PRIMARY KEY (capId)
);

CREATE TABLE siteContact (
  siteContactSiteId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  siteContactContactId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (siteContactSiteId) REFERENCES site (siteId),
  FOREIGN KEY (siteContactContactId) REFERENCES contact (contactId),
  PRIMARY KEY (siteContactSiteId, siteContactContactId)
);

CREATE TABLE profileTicket (
  profileTicketProfileId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  profileTicketTicketId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  profileTicketTotalTime SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (profileTicketProfileId) REFERENCES profile (profileId),
  FOREIGN KEY (profileTicketTicketId) REFERENCES ticket (ticketId),
  PRIMARY KEY (profileTicketProfileId, profileTicketTicketId)
);

CREATE TABLE sentryMonitoring (
  sentryMonitoringSentryId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sentryMonitoringMonitoringId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (sentryMonitoringSentryId) REFERENCES sentry (sentryId),
  FOREIGN KEY (sentryMonitoringMonitoringId) REFERENCES monitoring (monitoringId),
  PRIMARY KEY (sentryMonitoringSentryId, sentryMonitoringMonitoringId)
);
```

Comment: Sounds like you should find the db designer and strangle him/her!! LOL Seriously, can the data not be retrieved using a single SQL statement with various joins, and then simplified before generating JSON specific to the needs of the Angular front-end? If possible, show the table schema and relationships along with an optimized structure to return to Angular.

Comment: What is more important: user experience or data consistency? If app users have to, for example review and submit 100s of tickets, I would opt for smaller data packets and sort data in tables on server. On the other hand, if users don't mind waiting for a few seconds to submit a ticket, it would be probably easier to update and validate 19 individual requests... Another option would be Optimistic UI approach - send data to the worker for processing, and let user have smooth experience...

Comment: Another approach would be to get the most important info to display, and have various "Show Details" buttons that retrieve the additional info. In most cases, you don't want or need to display everything all at once.

Answer (score 0):

When writing an API, one of the fundamental questions you have to consider is: **Is this API for a specific application, or does it exist outside the particular application that's using it?**

The answer to that question drives a lot of the decision making process that comes after. In some cases, the (client-side) application is the key component, and the point of the API is to present the information for that application so that the application can work. So, in that case, you build the API such that it supports the needs of the specific application as best as you can.

In other situations, the API, although being built now for this specific application, will probably be also used to support other applications (typically mobile apps, but sometimes other web apps or even server applications). In that case, the API has a different goal - to be useful in a more general case. Therefore, it's more important that the API be easy to use for a wider range of use cases - i.e. probably more matching the business domain than the needs of your specific application. And then, it makes more sense to have the API expose a larger number of simpler endpoints if that makes it easier to use in different situations.

The sucky part is that answering that fundamental question is not always easy - and that's where your own experience and knowledge in your specific situation has to guide you.

*PS. I left off other options like, for eg, creating the simpler API and then building the complicated app-specific one on top of that. But just note that there are other options besides these two.*